# Using nosetests with distutils2

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils, nosetests, distutils2

I am trying to use `nosetests` as part of my building/publishing chain, which is based on `distutils2` (using the `setup.cfg` file instead of the "legacy" `setup.py` script).

Unluckily, when I issue:

```
pysetup run test
```

I get:

```
running test
running build
running build_py

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

...yet, if I issue `nosetests` from the same location I can see all my tests being executed. My directory structure looks like:

```
|-- docs
|-- my_package
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- foobar.py
|   `-- tests
|       `-- foobar_test.py
|-- README.md
|-- requirements.txt
`-- setup.cfg
```

and the relevant part of my `setup.cfg` file contains:

```
[test]
runner = nosetests
```

What am I doing wrong? The official documentation is less than perfect on this point...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
pysetup run test --runner=nosetests
```

I have the same problem and it seems to me that distutils2 doesn't care too much of what I type in [test] section (I can write anything, it never raises an error).

Anyway it won't run either, becouse both --runner and --suite options expect a module.

The only way I was able to run tests was with a "run_tests.py like" module that I put inside a package and than I call with:

```
pysetup run test --suite=package_were_tests_runner_is.run_tests
```